# Get size of array returned by map in React render

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm using `array.map` in my `render` method of a React component. It works but I want to know how many rows it's rendering. I'm trying by initialising `this.numRows = 0` in my constructor, then incrementing it in the `map` callback:

```
<div>
        <p>Number of rows = {this.numRows}</p>
        {this.state.members.map((member) => {
          if (member.display) {
            this.numRows++;
            return <p>{ member.name }</p>  
          }
        })}
      </div>
```

But this is still showing zero. Full code here: [jsfiddle.net/ra13jxak/](https://jsfiddle.net/ra13jxak/). How can I show the number of rows returned?

Comment: do you have members that will not be rendered in your `members` state?

Comment: In your constructor, initialize a state with `this.state={ numRows: 0}` then inside map within the if statement do: `this.setState({numRows: this.state.numRows+1})` then render `<p>Number of rows = {this.state.numRows}</p>`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might consider filtering the members you want to display first, then displaying the length of the resulting array, and mapping over it to render the members:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kz3b97ns/)

```
render() {
    const membersToRender = this.state.members.filter(member => member.display)
    const numRows = membersToRender.length

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Number of rows = {numRows}</p>
        {
          membersToRender.map((member, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{ member.name }</p>
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Edit: Thanks Edgar Henriquez, I fixed the key properties warning as you suggested

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a good idea to extract it to the component:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ra13jxak/2/)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      members: [
        ..
      ],

      visibleMembers() {
        return this.members.filter(m => m.display)
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const members =  this.state.visibleMembers()

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Number of rows = {members.length}</p>
        {members.map(m => <p key={ m.id }>{ m.name }</p>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I've added `key` attribute to suppress a warning, you can read more about it on [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter to generate a new array and then use it to show the number of rows and iterate through it. Like this:

```
const members = this.state.members.filter(member => member.display)
return (
  <div>
    <p>Number of rows = { members.length }</p>
    {members.map(member => <p>{ member.name }</p>)}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use filter on this.state.members on a certain condition which is display attribute in your case

Just have a div wrapped around the elements and get the actually rendered elements count or you can use the use the length method after applying filter having certain conditions.

Implement Render like this:

```
render(){
    return (
    <div>
       <p>Number of rows = {this.numRows}</p>
       <div id="members-with-display">
         {(this.state.members.filter((value)=>{return value.display})).map((member) => {
             return <p>{ member.name }</p>  
         })}
    </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

You can have a function to know the rendered rows like:

```
getRenderedRows(){
//Either you can use this
return document.getElementById("members-with-display").childElementCount;
 // Or this
return this.state.members.filter((value)=>{return value.display}).length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use this :

```
{this.state.members.length}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use like this

```
this.state.members.map((member,index,length)
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old, but for anyone searching a solution on dynamic filtering (as I do), one may want to:

1. store the rendered (filtered) array into a variable (NOT a state):

   ```
    <div>
    {dynFiltered = products
        .filter((item) => {
            if (item.price >= filter.pricemin
               // && etc...
            )
            return item
        })
        .map((product) => {
            return (
               <div key={nanoid()} >
                   <ProductComponent product={product} />
               </div>
            )
        })
    }
   ```
2. In the function declaration, set a state value whenever the array-variable length changes:

   ```
    const [filteredQty, setFilteredQty] = useState(0)
    let dynFiltered = []
    useEffect(() => {
        setFilteredQty(dynFiltered.length)
    }, [dynFiltered])
   ```
3. Use the state value wherever it's needed:

   ```
    <h4>{filteredQty}items found</h4>
   ```

Iḿ fully aware this code is uggly, but saving the filtered array directly in a state turns out to trigger a 'Too many renders' error in React. Hope this helps...